# Cast Int to String inside Binding expression

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

Is there a way to cast an `Int` to a `String` in a binding expression that I am using in `android:text`?

For now I have a `BindingAdapter` set up to cast the `Int` using the Kotlin syntax `as`, but I was wondering if there is an expression to do this directly in `xml`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use databinding, you can do this: `android:text="@{data.toString()}"`

Comment: @Y.Kakdas And how do I import kotlin's `Int` in the layout xml?

Comment: ````<variable name="data" type="Integer" />```` inside <layout> -> <data> tags